# Screen Reader reading Title and description twice, once for <a> tag and for <svg> inside <a> tag

Tags: svg, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

If I use svg(with title and description elements) inside anchor tag, the Screen reader like Narrator reads the title and description for anchor tag as well as svg. So, title and description are being read twice. How can I avoid this?

Eg:

```
<a>
      <svg>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <description>Sample description</description>
      </svg>
    </a>
```

Comment: file a bug on the screen reader's bugtracker.

Comment: Narrator with IE11? Need some more details on the screen reader / browser combination where you are experiencing this.